# response time in apache bench

Tags: performance, apachebench

Which field is the max response time and the min response time and the average response time in apache bench result?

This is an example. In the apache bentch result, "Time per request" is 689.946

```
Time per request:       689.946 [ms] (mean)
```

I think that ,

```
"Time per request" = average response time 
min "Total" = smallest response time
max "Total" = largest response time
```

However, why "Time per request(689.946)" is large than the max total (longest request 680) ?

```
Concurrency Level:      1000
Time taken for tests:   0.690 seconds
Complete requests:      1000
Failed requests:        0
Write errors:           0
Total transferred:      355000 bytes
HTML transferred:       7000 bytes
Requests per second:    1449.39 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       689.946 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       0.690 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          502.47 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0   10  11.8      0      30
Processing:     7  110 186.3     19     658
Waiting:        6  110 186.4     19     658
Total:          9  120 194.1     20     680

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%     20
  66%     54
  75%    243
  80%    248
  90%    254
  95%    675
  98%    678
  99%    679
 100%    680 (longest request)
```

The "Time per request" and the "Total mean", which one should be the average response time?

Thanks.